# Listing all music files in a directory with their information

Tags: c#, .net, json, wmp

I'm building an application that needs to build a JSON serialization of an entire music library. It only has to do this every time the music library is changed (its a server and the music is sent to authed clients when requested).

I know you can get music information by doing the following

```
IWMPMedia3 song = new IWMPMedia3();
string artist = song.getItemInfo("Artist"); 
//etc for other elements (title, album)
```

So I'm wondering if and how I can use this to populate a JSON list with tables like so:

```
"Songs":{  "Artist1":{
           ["Album1":{"song1":"title", "song2":"title"}
                       , "Album2"]}, 
           "Artist2"{["Album1", "Album2"]}}
```

Or similar. If you have a better way to do it, I'm certainly open to constructive criticism.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid - can you update your example?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most maintainable way to reshape data like this is to first load it into a plain old object representation, and then use that to serialize your output.

In your specific case, you probably want to define the shape of your classes to mirror the JSON you want to create, for exampleL

```
class AllSongs { public Artist[] Artists; }
class Artist { public string Name; public Album[] Albums; }
//etc...
```

In more complex cases you may want two (or rarely even more) such representations - one that maps easily from input and one that maps easily to output.  That keeps code converting between the two representations relatively simple.

These extremely trivial classes are sometimes known as Value Objects or Data Transfer Objects.  In C#, you can convert an object to+from JSON using [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) - no need to download it manually, just add a reference using nuget.

Incidentally, I would not use this kind of Artists > Albums > Songs nesting because it's more complicated than necessary, and because some people perhaps want a different view (say by year, or decade, or alphabetically by song title, or by play count, etc.).  A really simple implementation is simply just one single class `Song` (or some such name) that has all the relevant meta-data fields.  That way different clients (or changing future needs) can easily group by whatever fields *they* care about, without needing to unfold your nesting first.

Comment: Would this hog memory? If I'm cataloging 10000+ songs, would this cause lag? Also, as to the idea to use a Song class, this software is being built to fulfill a very specific need of me (not planning to release it).

Comment: 10000 songs isn't much; let's take a stab in the dark and assume 1kb of metadata per song - that's still just 10MB of data.  I'm not worried yet :-).

Comment: So, just to clarify: I would make these classes (or something similar)  - no functions, just the variable declarations. Then iterate through the directories and create an object for the artist, etc. - then serialize it?

Comment: That's it!  In general, I advise to embrace pure-data classes (and structs), and not to feel the need to add behavior everywhere.  It's perfectly OK to simply model data when you need to... model data :-).  That's not to say you should never encapsulate internal state with behavior (methods), just don't assume you *need* to right away.  To reiterate the answer, you might want to read about DTOs/Value Objects.